# android under v 4.3 doesnt support for flex css3

Tags: ionic-framework, flexbox, box, ionic-view

I am developing and app with phonegap. I use the flex in my playfield, 
and for versi 2.x - 4.3 i use old flexbox, but i have new issue.

this my work for versi 4.4 - 5.0 : http://play.ionic.io/app/6850c655a6f1

but when i use display:box, http://play.ionic.io/app/b16f282b5a29. i want ion-item fit on height.

Please, help me to fix this issue ;(

Answer (score 0):

Retry adding some prefixes (as fallbacks)

```
.list{

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```